1990s teen action TV non-animated series: kid jumps into TV to become superhero
I've been thinking about this show I used to watch when I was a kid, but I can't remember the name.
It's about some kid and his friends. He spends most of his time in his parents' basement.
There's a TV in the basement, and this kid could "jump" into it and go through a transformation, eventually becoming some kind of superhero.
I remember the transformation looked like going through a huge slide, and I also remember this "slide" had a red/blue color.
Another thing I remember is that the villain in this show was a guy called "Mister X" or something? I'm not entirely sure but it was something with either a "mister" or an "x".
Most of the time I think he was shown in some sort of dark room with green lights.
This is basically all I remember about it.  I know it's vague but I can't be the only person on earth who has seen this show (at least i hope so).
The show probably aired somewhere between 1990 and 1997.
It was also American, and they spoke English. I'd also like to point out that this was a TV show with actual people, not an animated series.
I know it all sounds pretty vague but its really all I can remember.

Perhaps you're thinking of Superhuman Samurai Syber-Squad, which originally ran from 1994 to 1995.  High school student Sam Collins has a wrist device that allows him to enter the digital world (via a computer screen, not a television) and--looking like a rather menacing robot called Servo--do battle with digital bad guys.
His nemesis is called Kilokahn (voiced by Tim Curry), and he does sometimes appear with a greenish background.  However, none of the other baddies seem to be named "Mister" or "X".
Part of the first episode is on YouTube; does it look familiar?

you are spot on my friend, this is exactly what I was looking for. thanks so much. i love the internet/stackexchange :)
